# SAML SSO - How to configure a dynamic ACS URL (SalesForce is IdP)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

(My apologies, this is a re-post, I just found salesforce.stackexchange)

I am the Service Provider.  Also, a shout-out to this open source C# component (AspNetSaml), they made life a bit easier: https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml

Anyhow, when I send a request to the IdP (in this case SalesForce), I am providing an ACS URL and I can see that it is set here in my xml:

```
xw.WriteAttributeString("ProtocolBinding", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
xw.WriteAttributeString("AssertionConsumerServiceURL", _assertionConsumerServiceUrl);
```

(_assertionConsumerServiceUrl is what I really want it to redirect to, and I can see that it's set)

But what happens with Salesforce is that it always uses the ACS URL I was required to set when creating the Connected App:

[image]

I have my real ACS URL value blanked out, but that value is what it is always re-directed to.

There has to be a way.  Imagine if instead of redirecting to http://www.foo.com/, you wanted to instead redirect to: http://www.foo.com/?SomeValue=???? ... where ???? can be all different values.  I mean, if the user typed in http://www.foo.com/?SomeValue=1234, and it redirected to Salesforce just to sign-in, I'd like to be able to continue with SomeValue=1234, as that's what the original user intended to do (as opposed to going to static www.foo.com every time).

This has to be possible!  Thanks!

Comment: A RelayState parameter, that you add when redirecting to the IdP, looks promising!

Comment: Yes, you need a RelayState.

Comment: Ok good.  Confirmation.  I say that if that's the only option/solution I have, answer the question (instead of comments) so that I can give you a green check mark (and rep points)!  ...  Basically, I need to transfer var1=value1&var2=value2, so it looks like I might have to finagle it in some way because of the equal signs and ampersand's.  I'd imagine you can't do RelayState=var1=value1&var2=value2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RelayState is meant to direct the user after a successful login to a specific location in the application they're logging in to. If you need to include query parameters, make sure they're URL encoded:

```
RelayState=var1%3Dvalue1%26var2%3Dvalue2
```